# delay closing window javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I am writing a Google Chrome extension.  Thanks to everyone here for putting up with my silly-assed questions.  The routine is primitive but runs fine.  The only problem is that it runs so fast that it overloads the server and my ip address gets blocked.  So it needs a throttle.

The question is whether it is better to construct something with a timer or with setInterval.  After examining a particular page, the content script closes its window with self.close().  If I put this into a setInterval, I could delay the closing of the page and this would slow the whole process as much as the length of the interval.  Seems like a good throttle.

Now the last line of the content script is simply:

```
self.close();
```

I presume that if I modify the code as follows I would get my delay:

```
var t=setTimeout("self.close()",2000);
```

Will this work?  Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Did you try it? It should work. Are you experiencing problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd rather use :

```
setTimeout(function(){
    self.close();
},2000);
```

But your way is valid too...

Answer (score 1):

If the closing of the page is an appropriate point to wait, then this is perfectly fine. In this case, because it would appear to be a relevant place, then I think you are fine. Although I would use Christophes suggestion.

Using a setinterval to run them periodically will run into problems if your processing takes longer than the interval - as this seems to involve opening and closing pages, it could.

As a rule, setInterval is good for doing small processes regularly. In this case, you just want to put a wait into the processing, which suggests to me that setTimeout is better.

Comment: As it turns out, delaying the close of this window is not effectively slowing down the process.